BoringSSL-GRPC from Pods, React Native iOS simulation
I'm trying to run react-native iOS simulation. I already set up Ruby and Node dependencies, Xcode, and pod install. But I still failed to run the simulation with this error message:
CompileC /Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BoringSSL-GRPC.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/tls_record.o 
/Users/xxxx/Gradient/Grad1/ios/Pods/BoringSSL-GRPC/src/ssl/tls_record.cc normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')

I tried to delete the Pods file under iOS and reinstall again but it still runs into this problem.
Here is my set up:

Xcode from Mac App Store
Install Node.js and npm using Homebrew brew install node
CocoaPods: Install CocoaPods for managing iOS dependencies: sudo gem install cocoapods
Install Ruby dependencies bundle install
Install Node.js dependencies npm install
Install ios dependencies cd ios && pod install && cd ..
Setup Xpcde command line tools sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
Build the project npx react-native run-ios (I FAILED at this command here and the error message as mentioned above)


I'm cloning a project that I never run before. After setting up following the documentation, I failed to run the project using "npx react-native run-ios" command. I deleted and reinstalled "pod install" many times because it seemed like the problem from the Pods folder but I still got the same result

Already did. Let me know if you have any other questions

Much better, thanks. That level of detail should get you some answers.

I was running into a similar problem, seems like some issues with gRPC and dependent package updates is causing BoringSSL to be flaky. I fixed my problem by following the instructions in this link from user terrafant
https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/8020#issuecomment-2358890997
edit: I do not use inverstase, this is an issue that package also has with BoringSSL-GRPC failing. Some of those users use expo :)

Does this solution also work with Xcode and IOS simulator, or does it only work with Expo?
